# Pandas : How can I assign group number according to specific value?

Tags: pandas

DataFrame

```
pd.DataFrame({'a': range(20)})

>>  
    a
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  10
11  11
12  12
13  13
14  14
15  15
16  16
17  17
18  18
19  19
```

Expected result:

```
    a   group_num
0   0   1
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   2
4   4   3
5   5   3
6   6   4
7   7   4
8   8   5
9   9   5
10  10  6
11  11  6
12  12  7
13  13  7
14  14  8
15  15  8
16  16  9
17  17  9
18  18  10
19  19  10
```

What I want to do is to assign group number, from 1 to 9, according to its value.

The idea is to sort these values and split them into 10 groups and assign from 1 to 9 to each group.

But have no idea how to implement it in `Pandas`

Need your helps

Comment: Can you give us a usecase that we can work on? e.g. an example with test data set and expected output?

Comment: That's too broad. Show an expected output and what you have tried

Comment: See [pandas.qcut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe need [`qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html) for evenly sized bins:

```
df['b'] = pd.qcut(df['a'], 10, labels=range(1, 11))
print (df)
     a   b
0    0   1
1    1   1
2    2   2
3    3   2
4    4   3
5    5   3
6    6   4
7    7   4
8    8   5
9    9   5
10  10   6
11  11   6
12  12   7
13  13   7
14  14   8
15  15   8
16  16   9
17  17   9
18  18  10
19  19  10
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you wanted to create groups of 2 you can use this:

```
df['b'] = df['a'].floordiv(2)+1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using `//`

```
df['G']=df.a//2+1
df
Out[609]: 
     a   G
0    0   1
1    1   1
2    2   2
3    3   2
4    4   3
5    5   3
6    6   4
7    7   4
8    8   5
9    9   5
10  10   6
11  11   6
12  12   7
13  13   7
14  14   8
15  15   8
16  16   9
17  17   9
18  18  10
19  19  10
```

Comment: This one hold for only specific case