# Pandas - Python - how to subtract two different date columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, subtraction

Trying to have a column be filled with today's date minus the created_date column, but getting the following error : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

```
import datetime
now = datetime.date.today()
today = '{0:%m/%d/%Y}'.format(now).format(now)
today
data['Aging'] = today
data['Aging'] = data['Aging'].sub(data['Created_Date'], axis=0)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need subtract `datetime`s, so is necessary convert `date` in `now` and in `Created_Date` column, last for convert `timedelta`s to days use [`dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
import datetime
now = datetime.date.today()
today = pd.Timestamp(now)

data['Created_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Created_Date'])
data['Aging'] = today
data['Aging'] = data['Aging'].sub(data['Created_Date'], axis=0).dt.days
```

Solution should be simplify:

```
data['Created_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Created_Date'])
data['Aging'] = data['Created_Date'].rsub(today, axis=0).dt.days
```

Comment: thank you for help but this is the error returned from your code:TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('O') and dtype('<M8[ns]')

Comment: thank you so much for your help ( i need to learn about fromordinal) if  you can have a moment how would I input the following logic  , inspired from an excel formula: =IF('Aging'<16,"0-15",IF(AND('Aging'>15,'Aging'<31),"16-30",IF(AND('Aging">30,"Aging"<61),"31-60",IF("Aging">60,"60+"))))
I am currently writing over VBA Macro code and having some trouble as you can see on formulas - this logic(formula) would go into the column next to it 'Aging_Bucket'

Comment: @pes04 - I think need `pd.cut`, you can check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45273731/2901002)

Comment: @pes04 - special for you - `df['Bucket'] = pd.cut(df['Aging'], bins=[0,15,30, 60, np.inf], include_lowest=True, labels=['0-15','16-30','31-60','60+'])`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, try this as the full code:

```
data['Created_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Created_Date'])
data['Aging'] = pd.to_datetime('now')
data['Aging'] = data['Aging'].sub(data['Created_Date'], axis=0)
```

What you want, maybe:

```
data['Created_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Created_Date'])
data['Aging'] = pd.to_datetime('now').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
data['Aging'] = data['Aging'].sub(data['Created_Date'], axis=0)
```