# Unable to convert a column to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format

I have tried many suggestions from here but none of them solved.
I have two columns with observations like this: 15:08:19

If I write

```
df.time_entry.describe()
```

it appears:

```
count       814262
unique       56765
top       15:03:00
freq           103
Name: time_entry, dtype: object
```

I've already run this code:

```
df['time_entry'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_entry'],format= '%H:%M:%S', errors='ignore' ).dt.time
```

But rerunning the describe code still returns `dtype: object`.

Comment: Does it work with `errors='coerce'`? I think with ignore a single bad line forces it to return the input.

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful: [pandas-convert-strings-to-time-without-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375471/pandas-convert-strings-to-time-without-date)

Comment: The ```coerce``` option doesn't work. :/

Comment: This link raises more questions than answers.

Comment: The issue is that I need to subtract the two columns to see the time spent between them.
With object as dtype I can't do that. That Ed Chum answer is completely useless to me.

Comment: What is the exact datype of the entries in the dataframe column? (you can check with the command `df.time_entry.apply(type).unique()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the datetime accessor (`.dt`) with the property `time` and then you are not able to subtract the two columns from eachother. So, just leave out `.dt.time` and it should work.

Here is some data with 2 columns of strings

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['time_entry'] = ['12:01:00', '15:03:00', '16:43:00', '14:11:00']
df['time_entry2'] = ['13:03:00', '14:04:00', '19:23:00', '18:12:00']

print(df)
  time_entry time_entry2
0   12:01:00    13:03:00
1   15:03:00    14:04:00
2   16:43:00    19:23:00
3   14:11:00    18:12:00
```

Convert both columns to `datetime` dtype

```
df['time_entry'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_entry'], format= '%H:%M:%S', errors='ignore')
df['time_entry2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_entry2'], format= '%H:%M:%S', errors='ignore')

print(df)
           time_entry         time_entry2
0 1900-01-01 12:01:00 1900-01-01 13:03:00
1 1900-01-01 15:03:00 1900-01-01 14:04:00
2 1900-01-01 16:43:00 1900-01-01 19:23:00
3 1900-01-01 14:11:00 1900-01-01 18:12:00

print(df.dtypes)
time_entry     datetime64[ns]
time_entry2    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

(Optional) [Specify timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34790328/4057186)

```
df['time_entry'] = df['time_entry'].dt.tz_localize('US/Central')
df['time_entry2'] = df['time_entry2'].dt.tz_localize('US/Central')
```

Now perform the time difference (subtraction) between the 2 columns and get the time difference in number of days (as a float)

- [Method 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17191361/4057186) gives `Diff_days1`
- [Method 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37840872/4057186) gives `Diff_days2`
- [Method 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51646204/4057186) gives `Diff_days3`

```
df['Diff_days1'] = (df['time_entry'] - df['time_entry2']).dt.total_seconds()/60/60/24
df['Diff_days2'] = (df['time_entry'] - df['time_entry2']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
df['Diff_days3'] = (df['time_entry'].sub(df['time_entry2'])).dt.total_seconds()/60/60/24

print(df)
           time_entry         time_entry2  Diff_days1  Diff_days2  Diff_days3
0 1900-01-01 12:01:00 1900-01-01 13:03:00   -0.043056   -0.043056   -0.043056
1 1900-01-01 15:03:00 1900-01-01 14:04:00    0.040972    0.040972    0.040972
2 1900-01-01 16:43:00 1900-01-01 19:23:00   -0.111111   -0.111111   -0.111111
3 1900-01-01 14:11:00 1900-01-01 18:12:00   -0.167361   -0.167361   -0.167361
```

**EDIT**

If you're trying to access `datetime` attributes, then you can do so by using the `time_entry` column directly (not the time difference column). Here's an example

```
df['day1'] = df['time_entry'].dt.day
df['time1'] = df['time_entry'].dt.time
df['minute1'] = df['time_entry'].dt.minute
df['dayofweek1'] = df['time_entry'].dt.weekday
df['day2'] = df['time_entry2'].dt.day
df['time2'] = df['time_entry2'].dt.time
df['minute2'] = df['time_entry2'].dt.minute
df['dayofweek2'] = df['time_entry2'].dt.weekday

print(df[['day1', 'time1', 'minute1', 'dayofweek1',
        'day2', 'time2', 'minute2', 'dayofweek2']])
   day1     time1  minute1  dayofweek1  day2     time2  minute2  dayofweek2
0     1  12:01:00        1           0     1  13:03:00        3           0
1     1  15:03:00        3           0     1  14:04:00        4           0
2     1  16:43:00       43           0     1  19:23:00       23           0
3     1  14:11:00       11           0     1  18:12:00       12           0
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked.
I was able to create a column (tempo) with the differences between them.

The weird thing though is that doing a df['time_exit'].describe() shows the the dtype is object while doing print(df.dtypes) shows that dtype is datetime64[ns].

Any explanation for this?

Comment: IIUC, `df['time_exit'].describe()` is a Pandas `Series` with mixed datatypes and so it appears as ab `object`. If you are concerned about the `dtype` of a column, then you must look at the output of `df[col].dtype`

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of dt.time?

Just remove dt.time and your conversion from object to datetime will work perfectly fine.

```
df['time_entry'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_entry'],format= '%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. 
Doing what you suggest leads to the transformation of dtype to int64, but all the values of the columns are turned to Nat.

Comment: Can you show a few samples from your dataset on which i can work on?

Comment: This is the head(5) of the dataset with no conversion: https://i.imgur.com/Ufk7Tvz.jpg

Comment: I restarted the kernel of the notebook and now the output of the conversion you suggested changed (this is beyond science to me): https://i.imgur.com/YGv8V8u.jpg

Comment: Suyash, I copy here the answer a gave to edesz above:

Thanks, It worked. I was able to create a column (tempo) with the differences between them. The weird thing though is that doing a df['time_exit'].describe() shows the the dtype is object while doing print(df.dtypes) shows that dtype is datetime64[ns]. Any explanation for this?

Comment: It's dumb, I know, but I think I was fooled by the describe() result.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho i looked into your query,
I found this link to be the closest to your doubt .
Hope it helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018654/strings-in-a-dataframe-but-dtype-is-object