# Quantize row values into groups and compute average of each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create some sort of a sum-up of my data, that can be of the form,

```
A    B
------
10   2
20   4
5    6
5    8
9    14
```

I want to group these rows based on the values of column **B** by quantizing them in groups of a range of 5. So if some value of column **B** falls in the range *1-5*, the row will belong to that group. In the example here rows *1* and *2* fall in group *1-5*, whereas *3* and *4* belong to the group *6-10*. Each group will then become only one row containing the values of column **A**. So we would end up with,

```
A    B
------
15  1-5
5   6-10
9   11-15
```

How can this be done with pandas, without iterating over each row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binning column with python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273731/binning-column-with-python-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) with `arange` for bins with list comprehension for labels and then aggregate `mean`:

```
bins = np.arange(0, 16, 5)
labels = [f'{i+1}-{j}' for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])] 

binned = pd.cut(df['B'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
df1 = df.groupby(binned)['A'].mean().reset_index()[['A','B']]
print (df1)

    A      B
0  15    1-5
1   5   6-10
2   9  11-15
```