# Python Pandas : Make a Date Range of -2 +5 years e.g: 31 years -> (29-36) years

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Make a Date Range of -2 +5 years e.g: 31 years -> (29-36) years

My input is

```
     age          
0    31 years  
1    25 years
```

My Output is

```
     age       age_range   
0    31 years  29-36 years  
1    25 years  23-30 years
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @IMCoins i tried pandas.cut, but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) numeric values and then join together with add `2` and subtract `5`:

```
s = df['age'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
df['age_range'] = s.sub(2).astype(str) + '-' + s.add(5).astype(str) + ' years'
```

Another solution, thanks @IMCoins for suggestion:

```
#python 3.6+
df['age_range'] = [f'{x-2}-{x + 5} years' for x in s]
#python bellow
#df['age_range'] = ['{}-{} years'.format(x-2, x+5) for x in s]

print (df)
        age    age_range
0  31 years  29-36 years
1  25 years  23-30 years
```

If need regular ranges then use [binning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273731/binning-column-with-python-pandas/45273750#45273750).

Comment: I would personally use a string with the format method. It really is clearer to read to me. :)