# Pandas: Renaming values in a column based on a range of numbers that they fall under?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns that have a bunch of numbers ranging from 1 - 100. I want to split the values so that if a value is between 1 - 10, they are replaced with 0. If a value is between 11 - 20, they are replaced with 1. If the value is between 21 - 30, they are replaced with 2, and so on.

How can I do this with Pandas?

What I've tried:

```
dating["attr1_1"] = dating["attr1_1"][0:11] = 0
dating["attr1_1"] = dating["attr1_1"][11:21] = 1
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Binning column with python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273731)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the binning process with `pd.cut()`.

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series(range(1,100))
pd.cut(a, bins=[1,11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,101], labels=False, right=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an apply on all columns like this:

`df.apply(lambda x: x-1 // 10)`

This is call floor division: 2.9 becomes 2, 1.8 becomes 1 etc. Since 30 should become 2 in your case, we substract 1 from the value before we apply the floor division.

Answer (score -1):

you can create a function to perform the operations and passed it as an argument of .apply().
e.g. :

```
def function_name(rows):
    if row > 0 and row <= 10:
        return 0
    elif othercases ...

for cols in df.columns: # loop over all columns in your dataframe
    df[cols] = df[cols].apply(function_name)
```