# Create a new column in pyspark dataframe by applying a udf on another column from this dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, pyspark, count

My data is dataset diamond:

```
+-----+-------+-----+-------+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+
|carat|    cut|color|clarity|depth|table|price|   x|   y|   z|
+-----+-------+-----+-------+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+
| 0.23|  Ideal|    E|    SI2| 61.5| 55.0|  326|3.95|3.98|2.43|
| 0.21|Premium|    E|    SI1| 59.8| 61.0|  326|3.89|3.84|2.31|
| 0.23|   Good|    E|    VS1| 56.9| 65.0|  327|4.05|4.07|2.31|
| 0.29|Premium|    I|    VS2| 62.4| 58.0|  334| 4.2|4.23|2.63|
| 0.31|   Good|    J|    SI2| 63.3| 58.0|  335|4.34|4.35|2.75|
```

I have created a function which reads columns carat and returns interval for every value. I need to form a new column with this intervals.

Result should be like:

```
carat carat_bin
0.23    (0.1)
1.5      (1,2)
```

My code so far is:

```
def carat_bin(size) :
  if ((df['size'] >0) & (df['size'] <= 1)):
    return '[0,1)'
  if ((df['size'] >1) & (df['size'] <= 2)):
    return '[1,2)'
  if ((df['size'] >2) & (df['size'] <= 3)):
    return '[2,3)'
  if ((df['size'] >3) & (df['size'] <= 4)):
    return '[3,4)'
  if ((df['size'] >4) & (df['size'] <= 5)):
    return '[4,5)'
  elif df['size'] :
    return '[5, 6)'
  spark.udf.register('carat_bin', carat_bin)
  tst = diamonds.withColumn("carat_bin", carat_bin(diamonds['carat']))
```

but what I get is :

```
Cannot resolve column name "size" among (carat, cut, color, clarity, depth, table, price, x, y, z);
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Modifying your solution

Your problem is that your udf is explicitly looking for a the globally defined `df` and is not using it's `size` parameter in any way.

Try this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

@F.udf(StringType())
def bin_carat(s):
    if 0 < s <= 1:
        return '[0,1)'
    if 1 < s <= 2:
        return '[1,2)'
    if 2 < s <= 3:
        return '[2,3)'
    if 3 < s <= 4:
        return '[3,4)'
    if 4 < s <= 5:
        return '[4,5)'
    elif s:
        return '[5, 6)'

diamonds.withColumn("carat_bin", bin_carat(diamonds['carat'])).show()
```

This results in (I modified your inputs slightly so that one can see the different cases):

```
+-----+-------+-----+-------+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+---------+
|carat|    cut|color|clarity|depth|table|price|   x|   y|   z|carat_bin|
+-----+-------+-----+-------+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+---------+
| 0.23|  Ideal|    E|    SI2| 61.5| 55.0|  326|3.95|3.98|2.43|    [0,1)|
| 1.34|Premium|    E|    SI1| 59.8| 61.0|  326|3.89|3.84|2.31|    [1,2)|
| 2.45|   Good|    E|    VS1| 56.9| 65.0|  327|4.05|4.07|2.31|    [2,3)|
| 3.12|Premium|    I|    VS2| 62.4| 58.0|  334| 4.2|4.23|2.63|    [3,4)|
|  5.6|   Good|    J|    SI2| 63.3| 58.0|  335|4.34|4.35|2.75|   [5, 6)|
+-----+-------+-----+-------+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+---------+
```

For your dataframe, just as expected.
There seems to be a fundamental difference when using `spark.udf.register('carat_bin', carat_bin)` which always led to an error.

### Using pandas udfs

If you use pyspark 2.3 and above, there is an even simpler way to achieve this using pandas udfs. Just have a look at the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import PandasUDFType
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf

@pandas_udf(StringType(), PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def cut_to_str(s):
    return pd.cut(s, bins=[0,1,2,3,4,5], labels=['[0,1)', '[1,2)', '[2,3)', '[3,4)', '[4,5)']).astype(str)
```

Use this in the same fashion as the previously defined udf:

```
diamonds.withColumn("carat_bin", cut_to_str(diamonds['carat'])).show()
```

And it will result in the exact same dataframe as shown above.

Comment: Why are you not using the build in function in padas pd.qcut(
        diamonds["size"], q=5, precision=0, labels=False
    )

Comment: @TobiasBruckert because quantiles are depending on the actual data that you hand over, but OP wanted to have fixed limits

Comment: True in that cast pd.cut would do the job or not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273731/binning-column-with-python-pandas

Comment: Yes, in the question you linked it does, as it works in this particular case.

Comment: @pythonic833 still not working while using spark.udf.register. I am conditioned on importing only from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr

Comment: @user1997567: I mentioned that in my answer. I actually don't know what is happening differently with the udf and `spark.udf.register`