# create column with buckets based on value range in another column python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, apply

I have a sample df

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| X | 30 |
| Y | 150 |
| Z | 450 |
| XX | 300 |

I need to create another column C that buckets column B based on some breakpoints

Breakpts = [50,100,250,350]

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 30 | '0-50' |
| Y | 150 | '100-250' |
| Z | 450 | '>350' |
| XX | 300 | '250-350' |

I have the following code that works

```
def conditions(i): 
    if i <=50: return '0-50'
    if i > 50 and i <=100: return '50-100'
    if i > 100 and i <=250: return '100-250'
    if i > 250 and i <=350: return '250-350'
    if i > 350: return '>350'

df['C']=df['B'].apply(conditions)
```

However I would like to make the breakpts dymanic. So if I use a different breakpts like [100,250,300,400] the code should automatically create different buckets based on the breakpts.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: See the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273731/binning-column-with-python-pandas/45273750) and use `pd.cut()`.

Comment: Maybe I misread. By dynamic, do you mean that when you change the bins, the labels should adjust automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, `pd.cut()` would be the way to go. You can make the breakups dynamic and set them yourself:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

bins = [0,50, 100,250, 350, np.inf]
labels = ["'0-50'","'50-100'","'100-250'","'250-350'","'>350'"]
df['C'] = pd.cut(df['B'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

Have a look also at [`pandas.qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) which is a quantiles based discretization function.

---

Alternatively, with `np.select`:

```
col = 'B'
conditions = [
              df[col].between(0,50),   # inclusive = True is the default
              df[col].between(50,100),  
              df[col].between(100,250),
              df[col].between(250,350),
              df[col].ge(350)
             ]
choices = ["'0-50'","'50-100'","'100-250'","'250-350'","'>350'"]
    
df["C"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
```

---

Both print:

```
    A    B          C
0   X   30     '0-50'
1   Y  150  '100-250'
2   Z  450     '>350'
3  XX  300  '250-350'
```