# Changing values in a dataframe based on multiple conditions, using np.select

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, select

I would like to change values in a dataframe using np.select
However, I'm getting an error and google didn't find any solution for similar issues.
Could somebody help me out? Thank you in advance for your time and help.
Here is my dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,0,-0.6,-1,0.7],
       'B':[-1,1,-0.3,0.5,1]})
df
```

Then, this my code where df values are recoded as follow:

- values less than or equal to -0.5 become -1
- values greater than -0.5 and less than or equal to 0.5 become 0
- values greater than 0.5 become 1

  new_df = pd.DataFrame(
  np.select([df.le(-0.5), df.gt(-.5) & df.le(0.5), df.gt(0.5)],
  [-1, 0, 1]),
  index=df.index,
  columns=df.columns
  )

  new_df

[image: desired output]

My code gave me the following error and I'm not sure what's wrong and how to fix it
**KeyError: <function dispatch_to_series..column_op at 0x7f64a469d158>**
[image: my full error]

Comment: No it doesn't. I get the same error without constructing a DataFrame

Comment: Sure, I will restart everything and see. Thank you so much for your time

Comment: Hi Enke, after restarting my jupyter notebook, it worked fine without error. Thanks again

Comment: relevant to your task: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273731/binning-a-column-with-python-pandas

Answer (score 0):

You could try this instead - I believe rounding the decimals to zero digits obeys all your conditions as well :

```
# default decimals is 0 
df_new = df.round()

# or this if you need more control on each column decimal places
df_new = df.round({'A': 0, 'B': 0})
```

Comment: Yes, df.round() works for this particular problem. However, I'm still puzzled about why I'm getting that error. Anyway, thank you for your time.