# Setting conditionals to a certain column in the csv file I uploaded

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my csv file that consists of 273 different values. I am trying to set conditionals so that I can label them high or low that way I can then plot them on a basemp. The picture I attached is what I am trying to create with my own data. If anyone has any advice or tips it would really help. I am a first-time coder, sorry if I didn't explain it thoroughly. I am using python in a google co-lab notebook similar to jupyter notebook.

[Map I am trying to create that shows the high and low values through change of color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Siq3r.png)

Comment: You are looking for `pd.cut`. Take a look at the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273731/binning-a-column-with-python-pandas to see an example usage. You will want to change the labels from numbers to `high`, `low` etc.

Answer (score 0):

This pythonic code snippet is a way to create a new column of high and low based on the column of interest (COI) in your dataframe. Then you can run further visualization on that. It uses numpy.

```
import numpy as np

df['High or Low'] = np.where(
    df['COI'] >= 12, "High", np.where(
    df['COI'] <  12, "Low", -1))
```

I hope this help!