# 3d animated line plot with plotly in python

Tags: python, 3d, plotly, interactive

I saw this 3d plot. it was animated and added a new value every day. i have not found an example to recreate it with plotly in python.

[image]

the plot should start with the value from the first row (100). The start value should remain (no rolling values). The plot should be animated in such a way that each row value is added one after the other and the x-axis expands. the following data frame contains the values (df_stocks) and Dates to plot. assigning the colors would be a great addition. the more positive the deeper the green, the more negative the darker red.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

stocks = ["AAPL", "MSFT"]

df_stocks = pd.DataFrame()
for stock in stocks:
    df = yf.download(stock, start="2022-01-01", end="2022-07-01", group_by='ticker')
    df['perct'] = df['Close'].pct_change()
    df_stocks[stock] = df['perct']

df_stocks.iloc[0] = 0
df_stocks += 1
df_stocks = df_stocks.cumprod()*100
df_stocks -= 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list of `go.Frame` objects as shown in [this example](https://plotly.com/python/animations/#simple-play-button). Since you want the line plot to continually extend outward, each frame needs to include data that's one row longer than the previous frame, so we can use a list comprehension like:

```
frames = [go.Frame(data=

    ## ...extract info from df_stocks.iloc[:i]

for i in range(len(df_stocks))]
```

To add colors to your lines depending on their value, you can use binning and labels (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45273750/5327068)) to create new columns called `AAPL_color` and `MSFT_color` that contain the string of the css color (like `'darkorange'` or `'green'`). Then you can pass the information from these columns using the argument `line=dict(color=...)` in each `go.Scatter3d` object.

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

stocks = ["AAPL", "MSFT"]

df_stocks = pd.DataFrame()
for stock in stocks:
    df = yf.download(stock, start="2022-01-01", end="2022-07-01", group_by='ticker')
    df['perct'] = df['Close'].pct_change()
    df_stocks[stock] = df['perct']

df_stocks.iloc[0] = 0
df_stocks += 1
df_stocks = df_stocks.cumprod()*100
df_stocks -= 100 

df_min = df_stocks[['AAPL','MSFT']].min().min() - 1
df_max = df_stocks[['AAPL','MSFT']].max().max() + 1

labels = ['firebrick','darkorange','peachpuff','palegoldenrod','palegreen','green']
bins = np.linspace(df_min,df_max,len(labels)+1)
df_stocks['AAPL_color'] = pd.cut(df_stocks['AAPL'], bins=bins, labels=labels).astype(str)
df_stocks['MSFT_color'] = pd.cut(df_stocks['MSFT'], bins=bins, labels=labels).astype(str)

frames = [go.Frame(
    data=[
        go.Scatter3d(
            y=df_stocks.iloc[:i].index, 
            z=df_stocks.iloc[:i].AAPL.values,
            x=['AAPL']*i,
            name='AAPL',
            mode='lines',
            line=dict(
                color=df_stocks.iloc[:i].AAPL_color.values, width=3,
            )
        ), 
        go.Scatter3d(
            y=df_stocks.iloc[:i].index, 
            z=df_stocks.iloc[:i].MSFT.values,
            x=['MSFT']*i,
            name='MSFT',
            mode='lines',
            line=dict(
                color=df_stocks.iloc[:i].MSFT_color.values, width=3,
            )
        )]
    ) 
for i in range(len(df_stocks))]

fig = go.Figure(
    data=list(frames[1]['data']),
    frames=frames,
    layout=go.Layout(
        # xaxis=dict(range=[0, 5], autorange=False),
        # yaxis=dict(range=[0, 5], autorange=False),
        # zaxis=dict(range=[0, 5], autorange=False),
        template='plotly_dark',
        legend = dict(bgcolor = 'grey'),
        updatemenus=[dict(
            type="buttons",
            font=dict(color='black'),
            buttons=[dict(label="Play",
                          method="animate",
                          args=[None])])]
    ),
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: oh great! made my day! I am playing around to make it faster, bringing the lines more in the center and changing the x-axis ticks...

Comment: @Alex glad to hear my answer was helpful! you can definitely make some aesthetic changes – i believe the frame rate can be controlled using the `"duration"` parameter as shown [here](https://plotly.com/python/animations/?_ga=2.34650913.1095174710.1676255914-1789232123.1675635503#using-a-slider-and-buttons)

Comment: @ Derek O.  I have separated the colors into a separate data frame and I am trying to loop over the stocks in order to add each with go.Scatter3d.  I have more than 10 stocks to add (which would be tedious to do manually). Where should I place the loop in my code? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Alex i think you can use a list comprehension inside the `data` argument when you're defining `frames`. something like: `frames = [go.Frame(data=[go.Scatter3d(...use col as needed...) for col in col_names]) for i in range(len(df_stocks))]`