# I'd like to categorize the price of my dataset's bikes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I make a dataset which is about bike .Price of bike included into this datasets.Now I would like to categoriz the price into "cheap","moderate" & "expensive" based on the bike prices.

```
data2.loc[data2["PRICE"] < 50000,'PRICE_CATEGORY'] = 'cheap'
data2.loc[data2["PRICE"] < 520000,'PRICE_CATEGORY'] = 'expensive'
data2.loc[data2["PRICE"] < 170000,'PRICE_CATEGORY'] = 'moderate'
data2.head()
```

'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
[I have converted the "PRICE" into integer but the error shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFMam.png)

Comment: Can you post the output of `print(data2.dtypes)` ?

Comment: print(data2.dtypes)
BRAND               object
MODEL               object
BRAKING_SYSTEM      object
BRAKE_ISSUE          int64
RUNNING_MILE        object
ENGINE_CONDITION     int64
BATTERY_ISSUE        int64
DENT_CONDITION      object
TIRE_CONDITIONS      int64
SUSPENSION          object
MILAGE              object
BRAND_NEW_MARKET    object
PRICE               object
PRICE_CATEGORY      object
dtype: object

Comment: "I have converted the "PRICE" into integer but the error shown" please post all your code including the code that does the conversion

Comment: `PRICE object` Looks like price is still a string.

Comment: Also, do you notice, price < 52000 will also match all rows for which price < 50000, meaning the order of your assignment is wrong. start with expensive, then moderate, then cheap. Or else make your conditions a little more foolproof (eg price < 50000 = cheap, 50000 <= price < 170000 = moderate, price >= 170000  = expensive)

Comment: try `data2['PRICE'] = pd.to_numeric(data2['PRICE'], errors='coerce')` instead. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273731/binning-a-column-with-pandas

Comment: data2['PRICE'] = data2['PRICE'].astype(str).astype(int)

Comment: You need to use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)